# $H$ is a subgroup of $G$ and every coset of $H$ in $G$ is a subgroup of $G$.Then which of the following is true?

Tags: abstract-algebra

$H$ is a subgroup of $G$ and every coset of $H$ in $G$ is a subgroup of $G$.Then which of the following is true?
(A) $H=${$e$}
(B) $H=G$
(C) $G$ must have prime order.
(D) $H$ must have prime order.

---

Comment: Can you rule out any of them? Can you see that any of them must hold?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hint:-
(B) is true. every subgroup of a group must contain the identity and any two distinct cosets are disjoint.

Answer (score 2):

In spite of being already given the final answer, think of the following: if we have a coset $\,gH\neq H\,$ , then it can **not** be that $\,1\in gH\,$ (why?) , thus...

Comment: Dear Don, does $Q_8$ violet the problem? Thanks

Comment: @BabakS. how could it?

Comment: I don't understand, @BabakS.: how *and what* does $\,Q_8\,$ violate ?

Comment: @DonAntonio: I felt that if I considered a right coset of, for example $H=\{\pm 1,\pm i\}$, then I would have another subgroup of $G=Q_8$

Comment: @DonAntonio: This means to me that I can consider $Q_8$ and a subgroup of it, say $H$, but none of the options are correct. Sometimes, I feel, I can't see the facts, however, I have been with them for times. Thanks for the time and (+1).

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft: Don  is gone. Maybe you can light my mind

Comment: @BabakS. No coset of that subgroup of $Q_8$ is itself a subgroup unless it equals $H$. This is because the cosets are disjoint, and a subgroup contains the identity element.

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft: Ohhhh... I see that. I can see that. Thanks